# Can I use older DAFF files as HRIRs in VA?

Tags: audio

I have some older DAFF files from head-related impulse response measurements of the Fabian dummy head. I believe they are OpenDAFF version 1.5.

If I try to load it with the Matlab call

```
hrir_id = va.create_directivity_from_file( 'Fabian_2011.daff' )
```

I get the answer

```
[VACore] Could not load directivity, DAFF version not supported.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use older DAFF files in Virtual Acoustics, because VA has been built against the current OpenDAFF version 1.7. However, you can convert a DAFF v15 to a DAFF v17 conveniently using the [ITA-Toolbox](http://www.ita-toolbox.org), if you have Matlab at your disposal. The Matlab call would be

```
daffv17_convert_from_daffv15( hrirv15_input_file_path, hrirv17_output_file_path, [] )
```

You can also add further metadata, just add as last argument a metadata struct that can be created by

```
md = daffv17_add_metadata( [], "Measurement year", "int", 2011 )
md = daffv17_add_metadata( md, "Measurement microphone", "string", "Fabian dummy head" )
```

so final call would be

```
daffv17_convert_from_daffv15( hrirv15_input_file_path, hrirv17_output_file_path, md )
```

The converted DAFF HRIR is then compatible and can be loaded by VA.

Comment: Time to switch to SOFA ? https://www.sofaconventions.org/mediawiki/index.php/SimpleFreeFieldHRIR

Comment: You can also use SOFA files to convert them into the OpenDAFF format. Just load an `itaHRTF` from SOFA file and export it as DAFF v17 using `writeDAFFFile`.